# is there a programmatic way to check the correctness of recaptcha public and private key?

Tags: c#, .net, captcha, recaptcha

I developed an admin part of a website where the admin can disable or enable the re-captcha for the website also he can decide to use version 1 or 2.

But I stopped at a point where he enters the public and private key; he can enter wrong or invalid public or private key.

So Is there a way to check whether he enters a valid public & private key based on the request (current) domain ... I thought about connecting to Google APIs but I don't know if what I aim is applicable or not, and if applicable how can I achieve that?

any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the format that he uses to input such keys?

Comment: Those keys you got from google re-Captcha when you register the domain ! like '6LfySu0SAAAAAHIMs64Nmpnlx-sNqLG-WHyhz6WV' for example ... but there isn't any specific format for those keys

Comment: You could always use the supplied keys to show a Captcha on the page itself. If the user can prove they're not a bot, they keys are valid and can be saved

Comment: @Basic ... your approach is good, thanks for that great idea I will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Promoted from a comment]

You could always use the supplied keys to show a Captcha on the page itself. If the user can prove they're not a bot, they keys are valid and can be saved

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the private key by submitting an empty response to the [verification api](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify), and if 'invalid-input-secret' isn't in the 'error-codes' array in the result, the private key is valid.

However, that api doesn't take the public key as a parameter, so it can't be validated that way.

I too would vastly prefer some way to validate the public key on the server side, rather than asking users if the reCAPTCHA UI is displayed correctly. If anyone knows a way to do that, please speak up.

If this is really a gap in the reCAPTCHA api, I hope Google sees fit to fill it. I've submitted [an issue](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/163) to the project, hopefully something useful will come of it.